# Override dbt test naming convention

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbt

i have been working with dbt for a few weeks right now.
My project concerns data quality and dbt tests were the best fit for my environment.

For analytics purpose those test (the compiled one) needs to be stored so that i could extract metrics such as uniqueness, validity etc...
For now i simply need to store the test inside the following table :

| test_id | test_class | test_name | number_of failures |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hash_value1 | validity | source_is-expression-true_tablename_column1-column4 | 3 |
| hash_value2 | uniqueness | source_is-unique_tablename_column1-column4 | 5 |

For now i am struggling how to override dbt test naming convention :

> `jaffle_shop.source_not_null_jaffle_shop_customer_customer_id.49503e10e4`

I know i could use the name property for my tests but manually typing for hundred of tests or more is a not maintainable...

Any advice on how i should proceed next ? If i can't override dbt i will try to wrap the yaml in python code.

EDIT1:

In dbt, i am usinge a source.yml file to perform tests on the source of my data (a postgresql database). Here is a sample of how it looks.
Don't mind whether the test are relevant or not they are used as an example.

```
version: 2
    
sources:
  - name: jaffle_shop
    database: test
    schema: public
    description: A description etc
    tables:
      - name: customer
        columns:
          - name: customer_id
            description: Primary key of the table
            tests:
              - unique
              - not_null
              - accepted_values:
                  values: [1,2,3]
```

Here is the names of the test that results from running dbt test command.

```
08:47:38  1 of 6 START test source_accepted_values_jaffle_shop_customer_customer_id__1__2__3  [RUN]
08:47:38  2 of 6 START test source_not_null_jaffle_shop_customer_customer_id ............. [RUN]
08:47:38  3 of 6 START test source_not_null_jaffle_shop_product_product_id ............... [RUN]
08:47:38  4 of 6 START test source_not_null_jaffle_shop_product_unit_price ............... [RUN]
```

I want to modify the test name in a more elgant manner than just manually renaming them.

N.B: if my approach is wrong (to store the test name/results in a table) or there is a better one feel free to point it out

Comment: You mention "the yaml" I don't see anything that looks like YAML. Did you forget to mention that you want to dump the table as a YAML document containing sequences of sequences?  BTW in English you don't write a space between a word and a following `:` or `?`